# Kirchoff's law, can it tell me the direction of current in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, conventions

Say I want to find the current Ia in the circuit below:
[image]

If I use the approach of using kirchoff's voltage law and ohm's law on the left loop, I get

$-24V -12k\Omega*1mA -21k\Omega*I_a = 0$

$I_a = -36/21mA$

[image: My solution]

If I defined the voltage on the 21 kilo-ohm to be the other way around, I would get that $I_a$ is positive. The direction would change based on how I chose to look at it. Does kirchoff's voltage law not tell me the direction in this case, or am I making a mistake?

Comment: I think it may be because I'm not allowed to define the voltage as so? I would have to define the voltage such that the current and voltage obey passive sign convention?

Comment: You can define the voltages and the currents any which way you like, but you have to make sure that the signs between voltage and current across the resistor are proper. In your case this would give you Ohm's law with -12kOhm and -21kOhm resistances to make up for your choice. If you don't like that, chose the voltages on resistors always in such a way that the (-) is at the outflowing current in your calculation. Other than that, Kirchhoff's laws will over-specify the system of equations because the currents and voltages are not independent, you just have to make your choice of equations.

Comment: you should have posted that as an answer so I could pick you for best answer! thanks, lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't really remember the voltage laws, but I can tell you with only one source positive current always flows from plus to minus on a voltage source so Ia and Ib must be positive as youve drawn the arrows, and Ia is correctly negative relative to the "+" and "-" you've drawn on the 21kOhm resistor.

I recommend not getting stuck up in the laws and equations and instead take a step back and look at the physical problem. There is no way that current flows any way but down with that configuration.

Comment: While you can suss out the answer for these trivial circuits with this kind of *ad hoc* thinking there is no general way to look at the topology of a network and know the direction of current flow independent of the values of the components. The saving grace is that *it doesn't matter if you draw the current the wrong way* because working out the math will then give you a negative value for that segment.

Comment: For those of you that insist on downvoteing this answer, ask yourself, who is the better scientist/engineer, the one that can only use the equations to solve a problem and when the equations break down has no idea what to do, or the one that has learned an innate sense for the problem and can use that to guide their use of equations?

Comment: @dmckee, A never would have posted this answer for a more complex circuit. Certainly knowledge of the equations is valuable, but an understanding of the physical reality is far more important, and often people forget that when they get tied up in the equations.

Answer (score 0):

Kirchoff's laws say that the voltage on the bottom wire is some constant $V_0$, the voltage on the top-left wire is $V_0 + \mathsf{24~V},$ and Ohm's law gives us that the voltage on the top-right wire is $$V_0 + \mathsf{24~V} - 12 ~\mathsf{k\Omega}\cdot(I_a + I_b).$$ We can arbitrarily choose $V_0$ to be $\mathsf{0~V}$ or $\mathsf{-24~V}$ as you wish, but we cannot arbitrarily choose the potential difference across the $\mathsf{21~k\Omega}$ resistor because that potential difference must be 
$$\delta V ~=~ \mathsf{21~k\Omega}\cdot I_a ~=~ R ~ I_b ~=~ \mathsf{24~V} -  \mathsf{12~k\Omega}\cdot(I_a + I_b)$$ with the various equalities coming from Kirchoff's voltage laws across each of these different loops.

These get a sign mostly because there is a particular sign on this voltage source: if you tried to run the $\mathsf{1~mA}$ current the opposite way you'd get an impossible-to-satisfy set of equations. The further constraint that $I_a + I_b = \mathsf{1~mA}$ simply lets you figure out an exact number for $R$, because the effective resistance of the resistor assembly is $\bar R = \mathsf{21~k\Omega} + {\big((\mathsf{21~k\Omega})^{-1} + R^{-1}\big)}^{-1}$ and we know furthermore that $\mathsf{24~V} = \mathsf{1~mA}\cdot\bar R,$ which can be together solved for $R.$ Kirchoff's rules just give us this "effective resistance" expression, in this case.